# New SharePoint List Fields not appearing in New or Edit form

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm looking into an issue with a large SharePoint 2010 list (68 fields) where when the user tries to add new fields to the list, they do not show up.

I can successfully make changes to old fields, but every new field I add doesn't show up. However, they DO show up as an available field in SharePoint Designer and on the List Properties page.

I've tried enabling Content Type Management and making changes, (a common solution) but that didn't seem to help.

Anyone see this before?

Comment: This question is better suited to [SharePoint community](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I don't know what caused this, the solution was to use SP Designer to create a new *New Item* Form. When I did that, the new custom columns appeared.

NOTE: Simply recreating the New form was not enough. I had to create a New Item form with a different name and set it as the Default for that type.